# listFragment not refresh by findFragmentById on FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listfragment

I have a listfragment and FragmentActivity.
At oncreate I can populate my listFragment by this:

```
/**
 * Create and update adapter that can set list of user
 */
private void setListUser(){

    if(getListAdapter()==null){
        // init adapter
        adapter=new UserArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
                friends);
        setListAdapter(adapter);  
    }
    else
    {
        //update adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }                       
}
```

In my FragmentActivity now I want do a search (and upgrade my list):

```
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        ListUser lt = (ListUser)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listuser_fragment);
        if (lt != null) {
            lt.refreshList(newText);
        }
```

refreshList make a search (it works..) and I call setListUser() but I can't see a refresh. Why? notifyDataSetChanged() it works - I tried it. Thanks!

**this is refreshList:**

```
public void refreshList(String toSearch){
    friends= SearchUser(toSearch, this.getActivity().getApplication());
    setListUser();
}
```

Comment: if you can't see a refresh how can you find out your refreshList() works properly? can you post your refreshList() function Code?

Comment: refreshList works because if i use it when app call onCreate i can see a list. when i do a search by SearchUser it gave to me a not empty list but i can't see result..